# Harmon.ie Outlook Folder Not Automatically Saving to Sharepoint

Tags: harmon.ie

None technical User here! Please treat carefully...
I have Harmon.ie 6.5 and Outlook 2016.
I have favorited various email libraries in SharePoint and selected the "Connect Favorite to Outlook Folder" option but it will not automatically upload the documents -even if I force by clicking "Update Folder". I have colleagues who this does work for just not me..
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are customer. Already answered you via support channel.
Our forum is for the free edition.

----- Jean